# windows batch iterate over files rename with 0 padding

Tags: batch

i've been trying to make this little script. i basicly want to ask the user for a name, and then on that directory i rename all pngs to name+number, where the number is just a simple 3 digit iterator (000,001,002,003,...,010,...999)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /P id=Enter name:
set /a i=0
for %%f in (*.png) do (
set "n=000000%i%"
set "pad=!n:~-3!"
ren %%f %id%!pad!.png
set /a "i+=1"
    )
PAUSE
```

for some reason the iterator i is always 0, so only 1 file is renamed while others arnt since they would have the same name.

i did search this alot on the webz, infact i knew (and still know) very very little about this, this stuff is almost a frankenstein and usually code frankensteins dont work :/

thanks so much

Comment: sigh... This is the number 1 problem faced by people new to batch. Related questions come up almost daily on StackOverflow. Search "batch delayed expansion loop" and see if you can't figure out the solution.

Comment: found it, doing stuff with 3 hours of sleeping didnt help, so now after sleeping, i reread the same phrase 
"Notice that within the for loop we use !variable! instead of %variable%."

and it clicked me that i needed to changed 000%i% to 000!i!, thanks.

what should i do to this post? delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that will find all the missing files in a continuous sequence:

```
@echo off
set count = 1208
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /L %%f in (0,1,%count%) DO (
    set "num=00000%%f"    
    set "num=!num:~-4!"
    IF NOT EXIST img!num!.png (
        echo img!num!.png
    )
) 
endlocal
```

Notice inside the loop you need to use !x! instead of %x% to get a local delayed variable. But the loop variable itself is always referred to by %%x.